# How to validate children component in React form?

Tags: forms, validation, reactjs

I'm currently trying to write a tiny form Validation API, specifically the children components must:

1. not accept duplicate values;
2. accept values between a min & max value set
3. accept only values.

What is the best approach to tackling this problem in React?

```
<MyForm>
  <SingleInput />
  <SingleInput />
  <SingleInput />
<MyForm />
```

Comment: But why is your title shouting at us?

Comment: @Mureinik  your comment makes me smile :D

Comment: @Mureinik I didn't mean to offend...any ideas though?

Comment: @NatleyPhilip haven't got the foggiest - not my tech stack, unfortunately.